# theme custom component in element-ui

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I have actually been pluggin away at this for sometime. I realize the concept is probably alot easier than what im getting but I just cannot for the life of me figure this out.
For a code example of what im trying to do. Using the below code
https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/blob/master/src/layout/components/Navbar.vue
https://github.com/PanJiaChen/custom-element-theme

There is a scoped style for the navbar

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,21,41,.08);
```

I am trying to use the element-ui theme generation tool to override the background colors. I have been able to get all the colors to correctly switch with a toggle setting the color white like so.

```
$--color-white: #333333 !default;
```

This correctly changes the background of elements to a charcoal type color.
Now the navbar has a hard coded value of white, yet even tho I remove that I still cannot get it to change color? How do I target that navbar. Or am I just totally off the mark and doing it wrong. I am new to vue and element-ui just to be upfront.

Comment: Can't you just override the background color with `!important`?

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. I dont know if this is the right way to do it tho.

Comment: If it is fixed in the styling, kind of difficult so this is probably the best approach